# Cannot push project to GitHub using Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I can't push my project to GitHub. I always see this error:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I tried to reinstall

Comment: I tried to fix it using this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/). But nothing

Comment: Do the same thing with `user.email` as well

Comment: `$ git config user.name "Boiarskii"
fatal: not in a git directory`
hm, I can't set user name. But it's "Boiarskii"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117342/discussion-between-mihail-boiarskii-and-confiqure).

Comment: `$ git config --global user.name "Boiarskii"` you forgot the `--global` parameter

Comment: it was successfully changed. Doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **git-askpass-0.bat** file in editor and see the java file
   location in that file ("**C:/Program Files/Android/Android

   Studio/jre/jre/bin/java**"),
2. check if  the java file is missing in that path.
3. if yes, try giving your JDK java file location ("**C:/Program
   Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin/java**").

This solved our problem.

Path may be different based on your installation of Java and Android Studio.